# Is it possible to create new worksheet and add data from file to it?

Tags: templates, phpexcel, worksheet

I have file what have two worksheets which I wish to use as templates.

In php I create new PHPExcel object and load data from first worksheet to it.

```
    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('Page1');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('template.xls');
```

Then I need to create another worksheet in objPHPExcel and fill it with template from worksheet 'Page2' of file template.xls

But when I do like this:

```
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('Page2');
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $objWorksheet->setTitle('Sheet'.$sheetIndex);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($timesheetTemplatePath);
```

I get file with only last results.

How can I create worksheet and read data (with styles) from another file?

Comment: I'm trying to work out what exactly you're doing here. Your second block of code is loading the Page2 sheet over the same $objPHPExcel object, which will overwrite it. Why not just load both Page1 and Page2 worksheets in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing an index to `createSheet` method, in this case it would be 1:

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(1);
```